# ScrollTop function is not working with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, scrolltop

I am working on a popup window on a webpage, which ease in from top of window with the twin. I used the scrollTop function to apply the popup on scroll position.
i.e. when click a button, it appears on widow at scroll position.

The problem is it works fine in "Google Chrome" but in firefox it doesn't even show.

Here is my jquery code....

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $obj = $(".modal")
                , $overlay = $(".modal-overlay")
          , blur = $("#blur-filter").get(0)
        ;

        function setBlur(v) {
            blur.setAttribute("stdDeviation", v);
        }
        function getPos() {
            return $obj.position();
        }

        var lastPos = getPos();
        function update() {
            var pos = getPos();
            var limit = 20;
            var dx = Math.min(limit, Math.abs(pos.left - lastPos.left) * 0.5);
            var dy = Math.min(limit, Math.abs(pos.top - lastPos.top) * 0.5);
            setBlur(dx + "," + dy);

            lastPos = pos;
            requestAnimationFrame(update);
        }
        update();

        var isOpen = false;
        function openModal() {
            /*$overlay.css({
              display:"block"
            })*/

            TweenMax.to($overlay, 0.1, { autoAlpha: 1 });

            TweenMax.fromTo($obj, 0.6, { y: -($(window).height() + $obj.height() - $(window).scrollTop()) }, { delay: 0.2, y: $(window).scrollTop(), ease: Elastic.easeOut, easeParams: [1.1, 0.7], force3D: true });
        }
        function closeModal() {
            TweenMax.to($overlay, 0.1, { delay: 0.55, autoAlpha: 0 });
            TweenMax.to($obj, 0.55, { y: $(document).height() + $obj.height(), ease: Back.easeIn, force3D: true });
        }
        $(".open-modal").click(function () {
            openModal();
        })
        $(".close-modal,.modal-overlay").click(function () {
            closeModal();
        })

    })
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is with `scrollTop`?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: First of all thanks for prompt reply, And yes i think so, because it's working fine in google chrome, if you say i will give you css code too.

Comment: Yes there are some "janfoeh" but i think those are not related, here is the link for my webpage where i put popup, working in chrome but not in firefox - http://synoris.org/optin14/

Comment: @SameerKorde have any demo for us to play with?

Comment: Yes here it is - http://synoris.org/optin14/

Comment: i think the problem is under " function openModal() " in my cod

Comment: its not working means? what it is giving??

Comment: Sameer, if you reply to another comment, write an @ in front of the posters name, as in @SameerKorde. That way, the poster is notified of your reply.

Comment: @janfoeh Thanks janfoeh for the information and the answer let me check it it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript works fine; it's the

```
filter: url("#blur")
```

that does not seem to work. Remove it or try replacing it with [Firefox' standard implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()) of the blur filter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it worked fine now in firefox. :) Thanks again, though i want to Vote you. But my reputation stopping me.  They need atleast 15, and i have 1 as i am new.

Comment: @SameerKorde don't worry about it, I'm glad it solved your problem! But please mark the answer as 'accepted', so your question won't show up as 'unanswered' to others anymore.